# What is FCM INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I can't find any information about `INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR` when using the web push XMPP api but I'm getting a ton of these errors, about 8%... the message body is blank so it's very unhelpful what it actually means.

Comment: You'll see that error for all kinds of mis-coded scripts. ...pretty meaningless error but sounds like you got it fixed.

Comment: It actually wasn't emojis.... it's still happening on tons of strings. I can't figure out WHY. @RonRoyston do you have any other ideas?